# Array (class) filled with non nil values stays empty

Tags: arrays, swift, null

I am currently having trouble filling up an array of customClass.

I try to fill it with a jsonFile. During my json parsing (using swiftyJSON) i loop and fill my array.
The problem is, at the end of my loop, it is still empty. I tested it in different ways, and here is my code:

[image]

That's the file where the problem is. In my loop I fill an Annotation, that I add with append to my array. The problem is what my print return. Here is a part of it:

[image]

It's just a small part of a huge jsonfile. And, my tmpAnnot.name is correctly printed every iteration. But when it comes to my Array, nothing.

So I'm completly lost and hope you could help me ^^

(And for the information, here is my custom class) :

[image]

And btw, I tried to print my array.count, and it's nil too

Im so sorry if the question has been posted. I couldn't find it in the entire website.

Comment: You should post code rather than screenshot.

Comment: what good are optionals if people just put them everywhere and use `?` everywhere. The app won't crash but you won't find your mistakes.

Comment: Sorry Khundragpan, I already had the screenshots and I was in a little rush. ^^ And, the problem with my optional and my use of ?, is that it won't compile if I don't put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `JSONAnnotationList` declaration to be an non-optional and assign it an empty array

```
var JSONAnnotationList: [UGOAnnotation] = []
```

You see, you have never created an array so there was nothing to be printed.

The whole point of optionals is to use them sparingly, not everywhere.

Comment: THANK YOU. You just saved my day, it was the problem. I don't completly understand why, but i'll check that :D You da real mvp.